# iOS WebView url with javascript

Tags: ios, uiwebview

In Android, app can change webview's url with "javascript:alert(123);", 

then webview will alert 123.

I want to know is it can work in ios app ?

Comment: If your question is "Can we display JS alert in UIWebView" then the answer is YES

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Use this function `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString`. Read more about this function at [UIWebView class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006950-CH3-SW21)

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"alert('123');"];
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

P.S.: Use this function once `webViewDidFinishLoad` is called.

Comment: function stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString
can do the same thing, thx

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Here is a great article: True JavaScript+UIWebView integration in iOS7 -  http://blog.impathic.com/post/64171814244/true-javascript-uiwebview-integration-in-ios7